# Hover over show of Leaflet Marker from control panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

I have a map with different markers. The markers could be selected from the control panel. But, I would like to show the preview of the markers, when we hover over the marker tab in control panel.

If possilbe, the hover effect similar to the following [jQuery example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63923714)

Can anyone help me how this could be acheived? Following is the code:

```
// Map intialization
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 12.5);
// OSM layer 
var OSM = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// OSM HOT
var OpenStreetMap_HOT = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Tiles style by <a href="https://www.hotosm.org/" target="_blank">Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team</a> hosted by <a href="https://openstreetmap.fr/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap France</a>'
});


var singleMarker = L.marker([51.505, -0.09]);

// Layer controller 
var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
    "OSM HOT": OpenStreetMap_HOT
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Marker": singleMarker
};

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {
    collapsed: false,}).addTo(map);
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6khfcLem/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you something like grabbing the event of the marker? Like so:

```
$('.leaflet-pane.leaflet-marker-pane').hover(function(){
    alert('your code here?');
});
```

And from there call the tooltip event to show next to the marker?